# The quick access doesn't list other sharepoint site when trying to use CopyTo and MoveTo

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, copy-content

Please see screenshot below

For some reason I can't get to see other Sharepoint sites listed under quick access  when trying to use CopyTo and MoveTo.
Any reason why this is happening?
Any suggestions would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Do you have a OneDrive for Business (personal site)?

Comment: Callum nope i discovered that the account i was using doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have write access on both SharePoint sites and you don't see the site you're looking for in the list of sites in the left navigation or when you select on **More places...** link, you can navigate to the target site and use **Pin to Quick Access** to ensure it appears in the left navigation of the Move/Copy dialog.

[image]

After using **Pin to Quick Access**, try using Copy to/Move to from source site again.

**Documentation**: [Copy files and folders between OneDrive and SharePoint sites](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/copy-files-and-folders-between-onedrive-and-sharepoint-sites-67a6323e-7fd4-4254-99a8-35613492a82f)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.. will check this out and see. I think i click on Pin to Quick Access but it showed sorry something wen wrong

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works. If not, if you have access to onedrive you can use Add shortcut to Onedrive and then you will find the library in "My files" section above quick access section on copy to / move to dialog.

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out...it was a couple ofthings

Answer (score 1):

Please confirm that you are moving to the site that is not displayed in quick access, what permissions do you have?

1.Copy To, you will be adding documents, so you will need Contribute, Edit or Full Control or similar.
“Read” permissions to the source site are sufficient in order to be able to Copy content.

2.Move To, you will need at least “Add” permissions in the target site AND “Delete” permissions in the source site, as Move deletes the documents in the source site.
[image]

By the way, Copy to only copies the latest version, Move to moves all versions.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Thanks Xyza_MSFT I'm sure I have acesss but will confirm again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Trying to move files from one SharePoint site to another as an administrator (without a license !!!)

Solution: after adding a (temporary) license with OneDrive rights, I was able to Pin to QuickAccess

So add the right license and you are able to Pin to Quick Access in SharePoint